# Let users trigger python function call by URL

Tags: python, http, server-side

I have a JSON containing users' information:

```
[
    {
        'id': 1
        'password': 'abc'
        'email': 'abc@def.com'
    },
    ...
]
```

and a function:

```
foo(user_id)
```

I would like to write a Python script to run on my GCE server, which can send emails to all of my users containing a link each.
When e.g. user with id = 2 clicks his/her link, my server will run

```
foo(2)
```

What is the simplest way of generating the URLs and making them trigger the function on my server?
I don't know how to use HTTP but would love to take this opportunity to learn, I just have no idea where to start, as most python-HTTP tutorials I found dealt with client-side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using a GCE server, I recommend looking at Google App Engine, since Google will manage a lot more for you. This will let you focus on just the server code, rather than the server configuration.

Check out [this tutorial](https://medium.com/google-cloud/building-a-serverless-python-app-in-minutes-with-gcp-5184d21a012f) that shows how to deploy a simple python app to GCP and do something similar to what you're asking about.

If you *must* use GCE, you can setup a simple HTTP server in Python like [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) or [Bottle](https://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/) to run you code.

Comment: I do need to run on GCE, but bottle is just the thing I needed. Thanks!